# Write access to a subdirectory within a read-only directory

Tags: linux, mount, file-permissions

I have a home server for my website that is running on a mounted image. I mount the image as follows:

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=19489299 raspbian-stretch-lite.img
```

I then mount my static website folder, `www`, inside the image as read only:

```
sudo mount --bind www/ /mnt/usr/share/nginx/www
sudo mount -o bind,rebind,ro /mnt/usr/share/nginx/www
```

Unfortunately my repo folders for my home `git` server are inside `www` (i.e., `www/git/`). This has been an issue because I cannot push any commits back to the server (since the repo folder is in read-only mode). Is there any way I can have my `git` folder (along with all the repos, of course) have write permissions but have all the rest of the folders/files inside `www` remain in read-only mode?

Comment: Use permissions in the normal way?

Comment: Of course! This unfortunately means that I have to change to `777` so that "anybody" can write if I want to push remotely, right? Of course, I will have a `ssh` guard for pushing to `git` folder.

Comment: No, you don't need 777 and should not attempt to use it, not even as a "test". You only need to allow the appropriate user(s) and/or group(s) to write to it. You didn't mention anything about users or groups though.